# Hibernate : Class not found error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError), although dependency added in Maven

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I am trying to make a simple web application using Maven. On running, the servlet throws an exception saying java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration 
[image: Error]

According to the stack trace, the error is thrown at the line (18) where the Session Factory is created - [image]

The error says it cannot find the Hibernate configuration file, although the dependency is added under Maven. The pom.xml file is as below - (Note dependency hibernate-core v5.2.10.Final)

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>userinfo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>userinfo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-tools 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency> -->

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I crosschecked, the jar is is also added in the "Maven Dependency" tab and contains /cfg/configuration.class.

I don't understand what could the problem be. Please suggest how can I get rid of the error.

Some things I have already tried but neither of them worked:

- Changed the  of the dependency to compile.
- Updated (and cleaned) the Maven Project
- Cleaned and restarted Tomcat server
- An answer on a forum suggested that there may be a conflict between Hibernate versions used. This is why the "hibernate-tools" dependency is commented.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you manually copy `hibernate-core-xxx.Final.jar` directly to tomcat lib directory so that it will be loaded by tomcat at runtime. This is not the permanent fix, just to debug.

Comment: Also, I would like to know if you see compilation errors around `Configuration` class?

Answer (score 1):

Your hibernate tools is commented

Try to add this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.ga</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please refer to the edit.
Also, I tried changing the version to 3.2.0.ga. Didn't help :(

Comment: `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` class is in `hibernate-core-xxx.Final.jar` and it is present in pom.xml. Don't think adding `hibernate-tools` dependency to project will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following process:

1. Clean the project.
2. Update the project.
3. Delete the /org/hibernate/ directory from the .m2 repository.
4. Build the project.
5. Deploy the build.

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing all of that but still not help 

The problem was apparently because of version conflicts. I added all the dependencies in the same version and that seemed to help.

Comment: That is what deleting the conflicted versions solved the issue.